# getting mvc-mini-profiler to show some data to all users

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I am using the excellent MVC Mini Profiler for an internal project, but would like to get it to show timing information, no matter who you are. ideally, i would like to be able to show the full profiling information if the user is an admin or developer of the site, and show just overall timing info if the user is just a standard user...

would MVC mini profiler be the way to go, or should i just add stopwatches to the site? We are using Solr for our backend, so i would like to be able to say "Solr got results in x miliseconds and we rendered the page in y miliseconds" which we can do (to an extent) at the moment but only for developers... can we get those numbers from the profiler, and then display them ourselves, or am i embarking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MiniProfiler is probably fine or you could register a global filter similar to the code below. Obviously style appropriately for your scenario (see the response.Write(...) portion near the bottom).

I can't take credit for the filter because I found something nearly identical on a blog (don't remember where, though).

```
/// <summary>
/// Filter to display the execution time of both the action and result
/// </summary>
public class RequestTimingFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a Stopwatch instance for the specific context to gather
    /// diagnostics timing for
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Stopwatch GetTimer(ControllerContext context, string name)
    {
        var key = string.Format("__timer__{0}", name);
        if (context.HttpContext.Items.Contains(key))
        {
            return (Stopwatch)context.HttpContext.Items[key];
        }

        var result = new Stopwatch();
        context.HttpContext.Items[key] = result;
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called before an action method executes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        GetTimer(filterContext, "action").Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after the action method executes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        GetTimer(filterContext, "action").Stop();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called before an action result executes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        GetTimer(filterContext, "render").Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after an action result executes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var renderTimer = GetTimer(filterContext, "render");
        renderTimer.Stop();

        var actionTimer = GetTimer(filterContext, "action");
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (response.ContentType == "text/html")
        {
            response.Write(
              string.Format(
                "<div style='font-size: 70%; font-weight: bold; color: #888;'>Action '{0} :: {1}'<br /> Execute: {2}ms, Render: {3}ms.</div>",
                filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"],
                filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"],
                actionTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                renderTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds
                )
              );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. very handy. Will look into implimenting this... Off hand, before i get around to use it, does it interfear with mini-profiler? Thanks.

Comment: No. It shouldn't affect mini-profiler. It's simply a MVC ActionFilter that captures the start/finish times of the action/result and displays the deltas in your page. It may show up in the execution profile on mini-profiler, but that is all.

Comment: Any luck with the actionfilter?

Comment: ActionFilter code up top works grand, just having problems trying to get it to output in the correct place (outputs AFTER the closing HTML tag in current form... need to tweak it). but it works as planned.

Comment: Yep. I never got around to it, but it may be worth taking the hard-coded style info out of the output markup and just giving the div tag an id. Then you could probably use CSS to move it or use some jQuery to toggle the display? Just an idea.